# preg_replace background URL in CSS attribute

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace

I'm using `file_get_contents()` to get source code of a page but I fail in some websites that uses CSS like this:

```
background: url("/media/image")
background: url(/media/image)
background: url('/media/image')
// etc...
```

Now, I want to know how can I edit that CSS and add my website, so it will look like this:

```
background: url("http: //example.com/media/image")
background: url('http: //example.com/media/image')
background: url(http://example/media/image)
// etc...
```

. Here is my code:

```
$regex = "-(src\s*=\s*['\"])(((?!'|\"|http://|https://|//).)*)(['\"])-i";
```

I'm doing this on the `src` attribute of an HTML tag. I hope I'm helping

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, your comments are getting confusing. I thought this is what you were trying to accomplish `echo preg_replace('~url\(("|\')?/?(.*?)(?:\1)?\)~', 'url($1http://www.example.com/$2$1)', $css) . "\n";`, no? Where `$css` is one of your three examples.

Comment: can u tell me what this code is doing?

Comment: @chris85 -(src\s*=\s*['\"])(((?!'|\"|http://|https://|//).)*)(['\"])-i how can I add href attribute to src please?

Comment: I want this regex code -(src\s*=\s*['\"])(((?!'|\"|http://|https://|//).)*)(['\"])-i to be working with href attribute too not only src :/

Comment: You are much too fast at commenting can you what +/- 5 minutes for a response? I don't know exactly what your regex is doing from a quick glance but my guess would be you could group the `src` with `href` separated by an or it would work for both, presuming it works separately currently. This doesn't use what your examples are/were though. If my example works I can update with what it is doing. It doesn't doing anything with href or src as your examples had neither.

Comment: Perhaps you should clerify what exactly you want? What are you trying to accomplish? Are you trying to edit the source code of what's imported with `file_get_contents()`? To me it pretty much sounds like you're importing someone elses website and replace the stuff you can't import. Something smells a bit to much like phishing here..

Comment: @chris85 your code works great but how can I do if I want to replace http://example.com/ only in urls that don't start with url("//") or that start with url("http://") or url("https://")

Comment: Fiddle around with this, http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6c198cd5259c8dc17140f74b2b03c4366b9a8875 doesn't work with protocol-less URLs currently.

Comment: @thehelper Do you still need an answer for this after chris85 have posted his sandbox?

Comment: @5ervant yes how can I do if I want to replace example.com only in urls that don't start with url("//") or that start with url("http://") or url("https://")

Answer (score 2):

This `$regex` will replace the `background: url(["|']?$URL["|']?)` with `["|']?$img["|']?`:

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
$img = "http://placehold.it/350x150";

$regex = '/(background: url\((["|\']?))(.+)(["|\']?\))/';
$replacement = "$1$img$4";
$homepage = preg_replace($regex, $replacement, $homepage);

echo $homepage;
```

Comment: This regex: `$regex = '/(background-image: url\(\')(.+)("|\'\))/';` with this replacement: `$replacement = "$1$img$3";` worked better for me. Basically leaves `background-image: url('` and `')` in place and insterts the URL between, not touching the quotation marks.

Comment: @GiffordN. Is that regex meets the OP requirements?

Comment: Probably not for the op, that's why I left as comment instead of editing your post. Unfortunately your regex caused a CSS error because it retains the first `'` but not the second `'`, just the `)` so it broke the CSS. I was just addressing that issue for whoever may experience a similar problem using your code, since this is how I fixed the issue.

Comment: @GiffordN. I think your `url\(\')(.+)("|\'\)` should become `url\(\'(.+)\'\)`.

Comment: @GiffordN. You're welcome, but you should give an upvote if you think the post have helped you..